# How Do I Display a Pandas Dataframe as a table in a simple Kivy App?

Tags: python, pandas, kivy

I would like to build a simple Kivy app that:

1. Asks the user to input an integer (MTP)
2. Asks the user to input a delay interval (delay)
3. Queries a url after the user presses a submit button and then from
   the query creates a pandas dataframe that is displayed (like a
   table) on the main screen of the Kivy app and then the output
   dataframe is updated until the MTP and delay interval are up

I have all the code functioning for the query as a regular python program, I just don't know how to have the user input and the output dataframe (and a time stamp) displayed. (See below)

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import itertools
import pandas as pd

mtp = input("Input whole number of minutes to post:") #<-How to do on Kivy Screen
delay = input("Enter 15, 30 or 60 second delay:") #<-How to ask on Kivy Screen
STP = int(mtp)*60

def requestOdds():
    url = "https://WEBPAGE WITH ODDS DATA.aspx"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    stamp = datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    tbPPosts = ('rptOdds_ctl01_tdOdd', 'rptOdds_ctl02_tdOdd','rptOdds_ctl03_tdOdd','rptOdds_ctl04_tdOdd','rptOdds_ctl05_tdOdd','rptOdds_ctl06_tdOdd','rptOdds_ctl07_tdOdd','rptOdds_ctl08_tdOdd','rptOdds_ctl09_tdOdd','rptOdds_ctl10_tdOdd','rptOdds_ctl11_tdOdd','rptOdds_ctl12_tdOdd','rptOdds_ct113_tdOdd','rptOdds_ct114_tdOdd','rptOdds_ct115_tdOdd','rptOdds_ct116_tdOdd','rptOdds_ct117_tdOdd','rptOdds_ct118_tdOdd','rptOdds_ct119_tdOdd','rptOdds_ct120_tdOdd','rptOdds_ct121_tdOdd')
    mlPPosts = ('rptOdds_ctl01_tdMl','rptOdds_ctl02_tdMl','rptOdds_ctl03_tdMl','rptOdds_ctl04_tdMl','rptOdds_ctl05_tdMl','rptOdds_ctl06_tdMl','rptOdds_ctl07_tdMl','rptOdds_ctl08_tdMl','rptOdds_ctl09_tdOdd','rptOdds_ctl10_tdMl','rptOdds_ctl11_tdMl','rptOdds_ctl12_tdMl','rptOdds_ct113_tdMl','rptOdds_ct114_tdMl','rptOdds_ct115_tdMl','rptOdds_ct116_tdMl', 'rptOdds_ct117_tdMl','rptOdds_ct118_tdMl','rptOdds_ct119_tdMl','rptOdds_ct120_tdMl','rptOdds_ct121_tdMl')
    trimmed_text=[]
    trimmed_text2=[]
    tbodds = []
    mlodds = []
    odds = []

    for horse in tbPPosts:
        table = soup.find('td', {"odds-table-odd"}, id=horse)
        if table is not None:
            text = table.renderContents()
            trimmed_text = text.strip()
            tbodds.append(trimmed_text) 

    for mlhorse in mlPPosts:
        table2 = soup.find('td', {"odds-table-ml"}, id=mlhorse)
        if table2 is not None:
            text2 = table2.renderContents()
            trimmed_text2 = text2.strip()
            mlodds.append(trimmed_text2)

    mlodds = itertools.ifilterfalse(lambda x: x=='', mlodds) #faster
    tbodds = itertools.ifilterfalse(lambda x: x=='', tbodds)
    oddsDict = dict(zip(mlodds, tbodds))
    **odds = pd.DataFrame(list(oddsDict.iteritems()), columns=['ML','TB'])
    print odds, stamp** #<--How do I get these to print onto the Kivy Screen?

def getLiveOdds():
    interval = 0
    while interval <= STP:
        requestOdds()
        time.sleep(delay)
        interval +=delay

getLiveOdds()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't have much kivy experience specifically, but I suspect converting the DataFrame to html will be the best way- there's a `DataFrame.to_html()` method, the rest would depend on what options you have for displaying html within a Kivy app.

Comment: I haven't found anything that makes that work for me.  I'm still seeking an answer.  If anyone is reading this, I really just need to know the part about how to get Kivy to print a pandas dataframe table or even a python dict in a window.  I can make the rest work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out something which could help you :

Kivy file

```
GraphDraw:

<GraphDraw>:

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Hello World"
            on_press: root.graph()
```

Logic

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8

import datetime
import pandas as pd
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import dfgui
import pandas as pd


class Visualisation(App):
    pass

class GraphDraw(BoxLayout):
    def graph(self):
        xls = pd.read_excel('filepath')
        #df = pd.DataFrame.xls
        dfgui.show(xls)
        #print xls

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Visualisation().run()
```

So you use dfgui which can create pandas dataframe table instead of using Kivy.
See the project dfgui : https://github.com/bluenote10/PandasDataFrameGUI

I hope it can help :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will give it a try to see if that works!

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you find a better way :)

Comment: Helped me pretty much @Reekomer however when I execute, it is returning me type error `TypeError: String or Unicode type required`. Can you point what is wrong?

Comment: @T3J45, Happy it helped you :). Could you provide your code and the traceback? So I can see where the TypeError occurs

Comment: Sure @Reekomer , Please check this [link](https://pastebin.com/ZAhHzrBH)

Comment: Also, I added question here on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343100/string-or-unicode-type-required-for-dfgui-running-wx-with-kivy-python) it is.